# Impementing drop it function in javascript but the require answer didn't get it

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, array-algorithms

## Intermediate Algorithm Scripting: Drop it

Given the array `arr`, iterate through and remove each element starting from the first element (the 0 index) until the function `func` returns true when the iterated element is passed through it.

Then return the rest of the array once the condition is satisfied, otherwise, arr should be returned as an empty array.

```
function dropElements(arr, func) {
  let newArr=[];
  for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(func(arr[i])){
      newArr.push(arr[i])
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}

console.log(dropElements([0, 1, 0, 1], function(n) {return n === 1;}));
console.log(dropElements([1, 2, 3, 9, 2], function(n) {return n > 2;}));
```

- I get an output of a first test is: [1, 1] and
- the second test get: [ 3, 9 ]
  but the required output should be: [1,0,1] and [3, 9, 2];

Comment: The required output does not match the functions being passed. --- **1.** Why would `0` exactly equal `1`? **2.** Why would `2` be greater than `2`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: I think you're misreading.  The goal is not a `filter`.  It is to drop *initial* values that don't match the predicate, keeping the remainder.

Comment: @ScottSauyet good point. I did misread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also a fairly elegant recursive solution to this.  It's probably not very time- or space-efficient one, but it is simple and clear:

```js
const dropElements = (xs, fn) => 
  xs .length == 0
    ? []
  : fn (xs [0]) 
    ? xs 
  : dropElements (xs .slice (1), fn)

console.log(dropElements([0, 1, 0, 1], function(n) {
  return n === 1;
}));
console.log(dropElements([1, 2, 3, 9, 2], function(n) {
  return n > 2;
}));
```

Passed an array and a function, if the function returns `true` for the first element, we return the entire array.  If not, we drop the first element (`.slice (1)`) and try again, stopping when the array is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either set a flag when `func` returns true, or find the index of the first element where it returns true, or something like that. I think a plain `findIndex` and `slice` would be easiest here:

```js
function dropElements(arr, func) {
  const index = arr.findIndex(func);
  return index === -1 ? [] : arr.slice(index);
}

console.log(dropElements([0, 1, 0, 1], function(n) {
  return n === 1;
}));
console.log(dropElements([1, 2, 3, 9, 2], function(n) {
  return n > 2;
}));
```

If you had to iterate manually:

```js
function dropElements(arr, func) {
  const newArr = [];
  let found = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!found && func(arr[i])) {
      found = true;
    }
    if (found) {
      newArr.push(arr[i])
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}

console.log(dropElements([0, 1, 0, 1], function(n) {
  return n === 1;
}));
console.log(dropElements([1, 2, 3, 9, 2], function(n) {
  return n > 2;
}));
```

Comment: Your answer is 100% right, Ok, I'm a new developer and try to figure out lots of things here is my question.
If you have time, please explain why need a flag and the rest of the things.
@CertainPerformance